How to return a specific date range in a filtered table in sql server 2014
I am using sql server 2014 report builder.
I have a system that can schedule activity in different date, and I want to return activities that are scheduled in wed and fri only in the report. Then I want my report can be used to search those activities in specific date range and display like this:
         |    WED    |          |    FRI    |
(DATE)|AM| Activity1 | (DATE)|AM| Activity2 |
      |PM| Activity3 |       |PM| Activity4 |
(DATE)|AM| Activity5 | (DATE)|AM| Activity6 |
      |PM| Activity7 |       |PM| Activity8 |

I have filtered the activity date with only wed and fri results in WHERE clause as:
DATEPART(weekday, Activity.Starttime) IN (4,6) 
And the Activity.Starttime is in the format of dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.
Then I have used
Activity.Starttime BETWEEN @From and DateAdd(“d”,1,@To) 
in WHERE clause but it still returns all rows but not the date range I entered.
How can I return a specific period of activity date with the filtered table?
Thank you very much!

"but it is not working" what are you seeing? An error? Wrong results? Sample data and expected results would help.

It still returns all row but not the date range I entered.
I'll edited my question to explain more :-).
